# Como agregar texto a un text area

Tags: php, jquery

Mi problema no es problema, es una duda.

Tengo un text area en el cual el usuario escribe un comentario que será publicado en mi web, pero tambien tengo un código de comando que al presionar, por ejemplo `/`en el text area, se despliega una lista con los amigos del usuario para etiquetarlo en dicho comentario parecido al `@` cuando vas a etiquetar a alguien en fb, instagram etc..

Hasta aquí bien, lo que no sé hacer es al momento de que esa lista de usuarios se despliega (como sabran hay que dar un click sobre el usuario que deseas), etiquetar en dicho comentario para que el nombre de ese usuario tambien se agregue al text area. Luego en el submit, guardar la información en la base de datos con el comentario y la persona etiquetada en dicho comentario.

¿Cómo se haría eso? dejaré mi código de lo que estoy haciendo. Agradeceria cualquier ayuda o tips  sobre mi duda. **¡gracias**!.

**tag.php**

```
<div>
  <form id="tagcoment" action="tagcoments.php" method="post">
    <h2 class="texto">write your coment</h2>

  <div class="input-group col-12" >
   <div id="myUsers" style="display:none;"></div>
    <textarea><textarea>
    </div>

  </form>

</div>
```

**tag.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#tagcoment textarea').on('keypress', function() {

    var target=$(this).val()//obtenemmos lo escrito en el textarea

    if(target.substr(0,1)=="/"){//si del 0 al 1 es igual al comando / buscar amigos

      var target= target.substr(2);//enviamos es texto despues del comando /
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url:tagcoments.php,
      data:{target:target},

      success: function(response) {

          $("#myUsers").slideDown("fast").html(response);
        }
       });
     }   
   });  
});
```

**tagcoments.php**

```
 <?php

   session_start();
   include"conexion.php";
 $target=mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST["target"]);//obtenemos lo escrito 
 $my=$_SESSION["id"];

$sql=mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT foto,nombre,apellido FROM
registro r
INNER JOIN amigos a ON r.id=a.para 
WHERE a.de='$my' AND r.nombre like '%$target%' ");//esta consulta me devuelve mis amigos segun el texto que vaya introduciendo

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){ ?>
<!--imprimimos amigos segun el texto-->
 <div>
  <a href="">  <img src="imagenes/<?php echo$row["foto"]?>"><?php   $row["nombre"]." ".$row["apellido"]?>  </a>
 </div>
```

Como verán, el código es muy sencillo , todo funciona pero ademas de eso quiero que a la hora de la lista de amigos desplegarse que cuando yo le de click a uno de esos amigos se me agregue el nombre de dicho amigo al textarea como les dije es algo similar a los comandos de `@`.

Comment: Hola @andy_gibbs. Como verás, hice algunas modificacioes en la redacción y en la ortografía, ojalá en el futuro te puedas tomar el tiempo de redactar tu problema de forma más clara para que te puedan ayudar más facilmente con tu problema. Además, nos ayudaría a mejorar la calidad del sitio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Primero**: en vez de comprobar si el texto empieza con un slash, debieras usar una expresión regular para buscar el slash en cualquier parte del textarea.

```
var target=$(this).val();//obtenemmos lo escrito en el textarea
var match = /\/(\w+)/.exec(target);
```

Esto es: 'busca un slash seguido de uno más caracteres'. Si se cumple la comprobación, entonces `match[1]` contendrá el fragmento del nombre a buscar.

**Segundo**, debieras usar el evento `keyup` para detectar cuando se haya ingresado la primera letra después del slash. De lo contrario si escribes: `/a` necesitarás escribir otra letra más para que se cumpla que efectivamente hay algo después del slash.

**Tercero**: cuando obtienes la subcadena, ejecutas la búsqueda (en mi ejemplo, a falta de ajax, reemplacé el comportamiento usando una función que devuelve una promesa, que se resuelve con los amigos que empiezan con la subcadena)

**Cuarto**: cuando se resuelve la promesa de la búsqueda y recibes un listado de posibles amigos, se llama a una función que:

- Toma tu div `#myUsers` que originalmente está oculto **con una clase**
- Si hay amigos que calcen, le quita al div la clase que lo oculta.
- Por cada amigo, añade un elemento `a` con clase `amigo` al contenedor

En tu caso, el evento `success` de tu llamada ajax ya devuelve el html de los amigos, así que sólo tienes que verificar que no venga vacío y en ese caso quitarle la clase `invisible` a `#myUsers`.

**Quinto**: Declaras un listener en otra parte que dice que:

- Al presionar en uno de los `a`, dentro de `#myUsers`, se reemplaza la ocurrencia de `/texto_parcial` con `@nombre_amigo` en el textarea
- Se vuelve a añadir la clase que oculta `#myUsers`.

¿Por qué reemplazo con un @? Básicamente porque ya no quiero que el slash me vuelva a gatillar la búsqueda. Al cambiarlo con un @ se vuelve una cadena sin significado especial.

```js
var amigos=['alejandro','alberto','alfredo','pedro','pepe'];

function buscarAmigos(empiezacon) {
   
   return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
       resolve(amigos.filter(function(amigo) {
          return amigo.indexOf(empiezacon)===0;
       }));
   });

}

function llenarAmigos(posiblesamigos) {
  jQuery('#myUsers').empty();
  if(!posiblesamigos.length) {
    jQuery('#myUsers').addClass('invisible');
    return;
  }
  posiblesamigos.forEach(function(amigo) {
      jQuery('#myUsers').append('<a class="amigo">'+amigo+'</a>');
  });
  jQuery('#myUsers').removeClass('invisible');
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#tagcoment textarea').on('keyup', function() {

    var target=$(this).val();//obtenemmos lo escrito en el textarea

    
     var match = /\/(\w+)/.exec(target);
     if(match!==null) {
     
       buscarAmigos(match[1]).then(function(posiblesamigos) {
           llenarAmigos(posiblesamigos);
       });
     
     }
     
   });  
   $('#tagcoment textarea').on('click', function() {
      llenarAmigos([]);
   });  

  jQuery('#myUsers').on('click','.amigo',function() {
      var nombre_amigo=jQuery(this).text(),
          texto_mensaje = $('#tagcoment textarea').val();
      
      var match = /\/(\w+)/.exec(texto_mensaje);
      if(match[1]) {
         $('#tagcoment textarea').val(texto_mensaje.replace('/'+match[1], '@'+nombre_amigo));
      }
      llenarAmigos([]);
      
  });
});
```

```css
textarea {
width:95%;
height:200px;
}
.invisible {
  display:none;
}
#myUsers {
  position:absolute;
  right:20px;
  top:40px;
  width:100px;
  background:white;
  border:1px solid blue;
  padding:10px;
}
#myUsers .amigo {
 border:1px dashed #ccc;
 margin:2px;
 padding:2px;
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form id="tagcoment" action="tagcoments.php" method="post">
    <h2 class="texto">write your coment</h2>

  <div class="input-group col-12" >
   <div id="myUsers" class="invisible"></div>
    <textarea></textarea>
    </div>

  </form>

</div>
```

Prueba escribiendo `/al` en cualquier parte del textarea.

PD: básicamente, lo mismo que tienes ahora pero añadiendo la clase `amigo` a cada link que devuelves desde el backend, y declarando un listener para cuando hagas click en un link con la clase `amigo`.

Comment: Wuao que genial amigo este ejemplo me servira de mucho en mi proyecto , de verdad agradesco que compartas tus conosimientos con este humilde servidor de la programacion GRACIAS!!

Answer (score 0):

Al momento de seleccionar a la persona que quieres etiquetar guarda su identificador en un input, div o como mejor sea conveniente, si son varios guardalo delimitado por guiones, barras o comas.
Una vez que todo este proceso este bien solo envíalo a la tabla de comentarios donde deberas tener un campo 'personasetiquetadas', buena suerte con tu proyecto.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta pero no podrias ser mas espesifico ,ya sea con un pequeño troso de codigo para un mejor entendimiento ya que la teoria siempre es un poco enrredada xd